# События при нажатии клавиш на ios

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Возможно ли отследить нажатие клавиш "home", "lockscreen" на ios ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не будучи знакомым с React Native, смею предположить, что это невозможно, ибо нативные API такой возможности не дают, о нажатии на эти кнопки можно судить только косвенно при переходе приложения в фон и вызове соответствующих методов `UIApplicationDelegate`